# Scroll AndroidStaggeredGrid to specific position

Tags: java, android, staggered-gridview

I'm using https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/ in my project. Everything works fine, except I can't scroll it to specific position/item at will.

What I've tried so far (everything I could think of, enclosed in one piece of code for you to look at):

```
final StaggeredGridView gv = (StaggeredGridView) ma.findViewById(R.id.photosList);
gv.setChoiceMode(StaggeredGridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
gv.setFocusable(true);
gv.clearFocus();
gv.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // #1 approach
        gv.requestFocusFromTouch();
        gv.smoothScrollToPosition(index);

        // #2 approach
        gv.setSelection(index);

        View v = gv.getChildAt(index);
        if (v != null) {
            // #3 approach
            v.requestFocus();
        }
        //v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        Utils.log("scroll to " + index);
        gv.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Nothing seems to work and I'm begining to think this view has some kind of bug related to my issue. Is there someone who can help me in the matter?

Comment: What is the value of index if I may ask? I just had a similar issue with a GridView not scrolling and I noticed that the item I wanted to scroll to was "SLIGHTLY" visible on the screen and only if I moved it away completely did it actually scroll to it...

Comment: it depends on an last clicked item. Say it's.. 200 now and I get like 9 items visible on screen at one time. The issue is that my view is not scrolling _at all_ :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I wasn't able to scroll to a specific location, however, I did find that I was able to restore the state of the gridview.  In my application I had to implement a custom back stack mechanism, and you can pass the state which you can get from:

```
Parcelable state = mgridView.onSaveInstanceState();
```

The state is a Parcelable, so i was able to putParcelable in an intent, and then retrieve it and restore the state as needed, like so

```
if(state != null) {
    mgridView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

Upon restoring the state, it restores the previous position in the grid exactly.

Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue!